# ADB device doesn't show my device on one computer but does on the virtual computer

Tags: adb, device, android

I have Windows 7 64-bit. I also have a Windows 7 64-bit [Virtual PC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) computer set up on the same computer.

I have an Android device installed. It does show up under device manager under Android Phone as a Android Composite ADB Interface on both the actual computer (64 bit) and the virtual computer.

The difference is that on the actual computer ADB devices don't show any devices whereas if I attach the device to the virtual computer ADB devices shows it just fine.

It seems to me that either this is a driver issue on the 64-bit side or it is an ADB installation problem.

What to try? I have tried uninstall/reinstall drivers, power down, power up computer and device over and over.

I know that at some level I have the right drivers, at least the 32-bit ones, because it works on Virtual PC.

You may ask why I don't just use Virtual PC. Well, I will if I have to, but it is slower. I would rather use the real computer if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this [blog post](http://blog.tojicode.com/2010/08/opengl-es-20-development-on-android.html).

Based on the device you own you will have to hack your way thought the inf file as per the steps in the blog.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that blog you pointed me to was if the device wasn't coming up at all.

Answer (score 2):

Reno's suggestion did get me thinking, however (thanks Reno). I decided to try these instructions: http://nookdevs.com/NookColor_USB_ADB

It worked to do this.

I knew about that web page as that is what helped me get it working on my 32 bit computer. The reason I didn't think to do this was because on my 64 bit computer the Android ADB Interface WAS showing up in device manager and that had not been happening before in my 32 bit computer until I did those instructions.

My guess is that on my 64 bit computer the ADB Interface was installing, but not working because there is something weird about the 64 bit driver.

Now everything is golden and I am good to do. Thanks Reno for sparking me to take a second look at that page!